# Isomorphism of crossed product $C^*$-algebras

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

Suppose $A$ and $B$ are two isomorphic $C^*$-algebras, i.e, there is a $^*$-isomorphism from $A$ to $B$ and $G$ is a group acting on both the $C^*$-algebras by automorphism. If $\alpha$ and $\beta$ denote the action of $G$ on $A$ and $B$ respectively, then are the corresponding crossed product $C^*$-algebras $A\rtimes_{\alpha} G$ and $B\rtimes_{\beta} G$ isomorphic? If, moreover, $G$ and $H$ are two isomorphic groups acting on $A$ and $B$ respectively by automorphism, then are the corresponding crossed product $C^*$-algebras $A\rtimes_{\alpha}G$ and $B\rtimes_{\beta}H$ isomorphic?

This is a repost from Mathoverflow:
https://mathoverflow.net/questions/396774/isomorphism-of-crossed-product-c-algebras

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. Let $A=B=\mathbb C^2$, $G=\mathbb Z_2$. Take $\alpha$ to be the trivial action, $\alpha(g)x=x$; and $\beta(1)(a,b)=(b,a)$. Then
$$
A\rtimes_\alpha G=\mathbb C^4,\qquad B\rtimes_\beta G=M_2(\mathbb C).
$$

Comment: Now I see if $A=B=\mathbb{C}$ and any group acting trivially on $C$ would produce the group $C^*$-algebra, whereas a different action will produce  different crossed product. I am still little curious about the case of a continuous group rather than a discrete one but from my argument i can infer that the answer is still NO. Am I right?

Comment: Shouldn't the first crossed-product algebra be $\mathbb C^4$?

Comment: Yes, you are right.